# Como duplicar uma seleção de imagem

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar mais de um ponteiro como a mesma imagem q esta no css como faço isso??

```js
ponteiro = document.querySelector("#ponteiro");
```

```css
#ponteiro{
 background-image: url("../img/ponteiro.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="ponteiro"></div>
```

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: quero criar mais de uma imagem, da mesma que o ponteiro.. So criando uma nova div? e atribuino umm novo nome a id??
<div id="ponteiro0"></div>
<div id="ponteiro1"></div>
for(blablabla)
ponteiro = document.querySelectorAll("#ponteiro" + i);

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor seu problema? ainda näo compreendi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode clonar a sua div, porém isso duplicaria o id (o que não é recomendado). Então utilizando o atributo class você consegue selecionar a div original e clonar o elemento, se você precisar atribuir um id para o novo elemento eu posso adicionar esse tratamento na resposta.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ponteiro =  $(".ponteiro:first");
  $("#btnClone").on('click', function(){
      $('body').append($(ponteiro).clone(true));
  });
});
```

```css
.ponteiro{
  position:relative;
 background-image: url("../img/ponteiro.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnClone" value="clonar" />
<div class="ponteiro">texto para visualização do exemplo</div>
```